# sharing a post on social media through reactjs application

Tags: reactjs, facebook, twitter, instagram

I have a react based application, I want to post on social media such as Facebook, Twitter, and Instagram from the application itself without having a separate tab. From application itself it should post automatically on social media... it will be great if i can get some poc

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing platform. We can only help you with issues in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the APIs from the respective social networks. Each social platform will have its own developer APIs that are used to post from other sites. Like

Facebook - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apis-and-sdks

Twitter - https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries

Instagram - You can't actually post anything using APIs

You can also achieve this through other methods. Refer [here](https://www.git-tower.com/blog/automated-posting-to-social-media-platforms/)

Comment: okay...can u share any poc on the same